# Ngnix laravel docker project return error 502 bad gateway

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I tried run laravel inside docker container with ngnix.

**Directory structure:**

[image]

File `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx:stable-alpine
      container_name: nginx
      ports:
        - "${HOST_PORT}:80"
      volumes:
        - ../:/var/www/html
        - ./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      depends_on:
        - php
    php:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
        restart: always
        container_name: php
        volumes:
            - "../:/var/www/html"
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongodb
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        container_name: redis
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
```

File `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    libssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

Result of command `docker ps`:

[image]

When I tried open in browser address `http://localhost:8004` then get error:

> **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0**

**Ngnix config file**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**Env vars:**

```
HOST_PORT=8004
HOST_SSL_PORT=3004

# Nginx
NGINX_HOST=localhost
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you're using nginx as your web-server, you don't need to install PHP Apache (`FROM php:7.4-apache`) in your `Dockerfile`.

Instead try `php:7.4-fpm` and make sure nginx accesses that php-fpm correctly (line `fastcgi_pass php:9000;` in your `default.conf` file. In your case everything seems configured correctly).

One more thing to note that it's not necessary to expose `php-fpm` port 9000 to the host machine. As both containers (in your `docker-compose.yml`) will use the same network, `nginx` container can directly access `php` container. You can remove the lines

```
ports:
 - "9000:9000"
```